# Why normal convergence $\implies $ uniform convergence.

Tags: sequences-and-series

We say that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty f_k(x)$ converge normally in $I$ if there is $M_n$ s.t. $|f_n(x)|\leq M_n$ for all $n$ and all $x\in I$ with $\sum_{k=0}^\infty M_n$ converge. Why does it implies that the serie converge uniformly ? I set $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty f_k(x)$. Why $$\sup_{I}|f(x)-\sum_{k=0}^n f_k(x)|\to 0$$
when $n\to \infty $ ?

Comment: It's the Weierstrass M-test. The proof is short and can be found here, for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test

Answer (score 1):

$$\left|f(x)-\sum_{k=0}^n f_k(x)\right|=\left|\sum_{k=0}^\infty f_k(x)-\sum_{k=0}^n f_k(x)\right|=\left|\sum_{k={n+1}}^\infty f_k(x) \right|\leq \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty M_n,$$
and thus
$$\sup_{x\in I}\left|f(x)-\sum_{k=0}^n f_k(x)\right|\leq \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty M_n\underset{n\to \infty }{\longrightarrow }0.$$

Answer (score 0):

It converges uniformly (and absolutely) because it satisfies the *uniform Cauchy criterion*:

if $N$ is such that
$$|M_n+M_{n+1}+\dots +M_p|<ε \qquad\text{for all }\: p>n\ge N,$$
we also have for all $x\in I$
\begin{align}
|f_n(x)+f_{n+1}(x)+\dots +f_p(x)|&\le |f_n(x)|+|f_{n+1}(x)|+\dots +|f_p(x)|\\ &\le|M_n+M_{n+1}+\dots +M_p|< ε. 
\end{align}